# Error auto adjusting the size of a custom Dialog according to its title and content

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, autosize

I am creating a custom `MessageBox` for my program, the `MesageBox` follows a series of parameters to adapt it to the *Front-End* of the rest of the program.

Shown in the following scheme:

[image]

- *1 - Icon of my program (PictureBox)*
- *2 - Label for the `MessageBox` title*
- *3 - Close button*
- *4 - `MessageBox` icon (PictureBox), (be Exclamation, Information, Error, etc.)*
- *5 - Text of the message, where I use a custom `RichTexBox` to show the message content*
- *6 - Windows Form*
- *7 - OK / Yes `Button` (change via code)*
- *8 - Retry / Ignore `Button` (change via code)*
- *9 - Cancel / No `Button` (change via code)*
- *10 - `Panel` container of the icon, (Facilitates centered alignment of the `PictureBox` icon in center) has the `Dock` property set to `Left`*
- *11 - Top bar `Panel`, has the `Dock` property set to `Top` to cover the entire width of the `Form`, and contains the panels with the numbers 10 and 12*
- *12 - `Panel` container of the Close `Button`, (Facilitates centered alignment of the Close `Button`) has the `Dock` set to `Right`*

And here is the code:

```
public partial class CustomMessageBox : Form
{
    public CustomMessageBox
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs ev)
    {
        base.OnLoad(ev);

        this.TitleLabel.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            //Fit Width of the custom Dialog Form to the label Width
            int NewWidth = ((Label)s).ClientRectangle.Width + 
                           this.PanelIcon.ClientRectangle.Width + 
                           this.PanelBtnClose.ClientRectangle.Width;

            this.Size = new Size(NewWidth, this.Height);
        };

        this.ContentRichTextBox.TextChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.ClientSize = ((RichTextBox)s).ClientRectangle.Size;
        }

        //this.TitleLabel.Text = "Test short lenght";
        this.TitleLabel.Text = "Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght";

        //this.ContentRichTextBox.Text = "Test short lenght Test short lenght Test short lenght Test short lenght Test short lenght Test short lenght";
        this.ContentRichTextBox.Text = "Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght " +
                                       "Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght Test long lenght";
    }
}
```

The `Form` has the `FormBorderStyle` property set to `None`

Obviously I want the form to fit the size of its content and that as far as the title is concerned, the width of the form fits the width of the label leaving space for panels 10 and 12 and a space of about 8 pixels between the label of title and panels 10 and 12 as shown in the image.

The problem is that the form always keeps a small size, regardless of the length of the string of the title or content, so both the title and the content are incomplete ...

Example: `This is a title` it is shown as `This is a t`

> Note:
>
> AutoSize = true;
>
> AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
>
> This (without the previous code) only makes the form look like a thin bar 2 pixels wide and normal high.

**UPDATE:** This is what I want: The size of the form increases if the text is long, and decreases if the text is short

[image]

Comment: This is not a `MessageBox`, but rather a full-blown custom `Dialog`.

Comment: You could measure the text parts size (with [TextRenderer.MeasureText()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) in your Form Load() event (or overriding OnHandleCreated(), depending on how you're building this) and resize your Form based on this relative measure. Your docked containers will resize accordingly. The Message area probably needs to be anchored in all dimensions. `AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink` is *dangerous*. Also, read about Dpi awareness and prepare your code to adapt to it, too.